# How to delete all debugger in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

What's the easiest way to delete all `debugger` commands in a whole project using WebStorm?

it's a problem for me because sometimes I accidentally commit it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ctrl+Shift+R` (in Windows or Linux, and something different in Mac), or go to `Edit -> Find -> Replace in Path` to use the "Replace in Path" feature. Write `debugger;` into the search bar, clear the contents of the replace bar, select the `In Project` scope and try to execute the command. Make sure to verify that you don't accidentally replace something that you need (use preview).[image]

**Update**: 
If you'd like to remove the entire string, use the following regular expression: `^\s+debugger;\s+$`. Don't forget to select the "Regex" check box.

Comment: I will have empty lines insted of debuggers, that's not good.

Comment: @StanislavMayorov, then add a new line definition to `debugger;` in the search bar, just like you'd do to replace it in a single file.

Comment: I tryed this regexp `w*debugger;\n\w*`, but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Thank you, but only this regexp works fine for me `^\s*debugger;?\s*\n`

Answer (score 0):

you can replace all `debugger;` with an empty string.

Go to:

Edit->File->Replace In Path

Text to find: `debugger;`.

leave the Replace with input empty. In the Scope section choose the Whole project.